# ElseIF statement in classic ASP (VBScript)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

This is probably really simple but I have hardly any experience with classic ASP Syntax. Basically I have login statement. Shown below:

```
<%if session("AccountID") = "0" or session("AccountID")=""  then%>
                    <%
                    If request.form("SmPress") = "Pressed" Then
                        dim SQLVerifyEmail
                        SQLVerifyEmail = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName= '"&killchars(request.form("UserName"))&"' and Password = '"&killchars(request.form("Password"))&"' AND Status = 'A' AND Deleted = 'no'  "
                        set RSVerifyEmail = MyConn.execute(SQLVerifyEmail)
                        If RSVerifyEmail.EOF Then

                            response.write ("<span class=loginerror>Incorrect login details.</span><br>")

                        Else
                            LastLogin2 = "UPDATE Users SET LastLogin = Convert(datetime,'"&now()&"',103) WHERE AccountID = '"&RSVerifyEmail("AccountID")&"' "
                            MyConn.execute(LastLogin2)
                            session("admin") = RSVerifyEmail("admin")
                            session("AccountID") = RSVerifyEmail("AccountID")
                            response.redirect "profile.asp"

                        End if
                    End if
                    %>
```

All I want to do is split it, so that if the session = admin it redirects to profile.asp, but if it is equal to an account ID then redirect to profile-user.asp. I tried the following but it through loads of errors:

```
ElseIF
                            LastLogin2 = "UPDATE Users SET LastLogin = Convert(datetime,'"&now()&"',103) WHERE AccountID = '"&RSVerifyEmail("AccountID")&"' "
                            MyConn.execute(LastLogin2)
                            session("admin") = RSVerifyEmail("admin") Then
                            response.redirect "profile.asp"

                        Else
                        session("AccountID") = RSVerifyEmail("AccountID")
                        response.redirect "profile-user.asp"
                        End if
                    End if
                    %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not worthy of a full answer, but you've missed off the condition on your ElseIf. You need something after it `ElseIf something = somethingelse THEN`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only set RSVerifyEmail("admin") = "True" on the admin profiles in your database:
Give this a try:

```
<% if session("AccountID") = "0" or session("AccountID") = ""  then %>
<%
If request.form("SmPress") = "Pressed" Then
    dim SQLVerifyEmail
        SQLVerifyEmail = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName= '"&killchars(request.form("UserName"))&"' and Password = '"&killchars(request.form("Password"))&"' AND Status = 'A' AND Deleted = 'no'  "

    set RSVerifyEmail = MyConn.execute(SQLVerifyEmail)
        If RSVerifyEmail.EOF Then
            response.write ("<span class=loginerror>Incorrect login details.</span><br>")
        Else
            LastLogin2 = "UPDATE Users SET LastLogin = Convert(datetime,'"&now()&"',103) WHERE AccountID = '"&RSVerifyEmail("AccountID")&"' "
            MyConn.execute(LastLogin2)

            ' // Set only for admin session only for admins
            IF RSVerifyEmail("admin") = "True" Then
                RedirectWho         = "admin"
                session("admin")    = RSVerifyEmail("admin")
            Else
                RedirectWho         = "user"
            End if
            session("AccountID")    =   RSVerifyEmail("AccountID")
        End if
    set RSVerifyEmail = Nothing

    ' // redirect the logged in user or admin
    If RedirectWho = "admin" Then
        response.redirect "profile.asp"
    ElseIf RedirectWho = "user" Then
        response.redirect "profile-user.asp"
    End if
End if
%>
```

Comment: It doesn't throw errors but they both seem to redirect to profile-user.asp. Whether I log in with an admin account or a user account.

Comment: what value is set in RSVerifyEmail("admin") ?

What data type is this in your database ?